# How to run command line or PowerShell script if file could exist in two locations?

Tags: powershell, command-line, scripting

We have multiple systems with the same Dell program but different versions. The version number is the same but one is in the x86 folder and the other is in the x64 one as shown below. Could someone help me convert this to a command line or PowerShell script so that it would correctly from whichever location exists? It should only exist in one of the two locations and only needs to be run once.

Dell Command | Update

```
"%ProgramFiles%\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" /configure -updatetype=bios,firmware,driver,application,utility,others
"%ProgramFiles%\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" /applyupdates -reboot=enable -autosuspendbitlocker=enable
```

Dell Command | Update for Windows Universal

```
%programfiles(x86)%\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" /configure -updatetype=bios,firmware,driver,application,utility,others
%programfiles(x86)%\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe" /applyupdates -reboot=enable -autosuspendbitlocker=enable
```

Comment: We would like to see your attempt at this first.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell, iterate over the paths and use `Test-Path` to make sure the path exists:

```
$possiblePaths =
  "$env:ProgramFiles\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe",
  "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Dell\CommandUpdate\dcu-cli.exe"

$correctPath = foreach( $path in $possiblePaths ) {
  if( Test-Path -PathType Leaf $path ) {
    $path
    break
  }
}

if( !$correctPath ) {
  throw "Could not find dcu-cli.exe at any of the following paths: $(@( $possiblePaths ) -join ', ')"
}

# Execute found binary
& $correctPath /configure -updatetype='bios,firmware,driver,application,utility,others'
```

After the loop, check that `$correctPath` doesn't have a "falsey" evaluation (in this case, not `$null` or `[string]::Empty`). If it evaluates to `$False`, the file was not found in any of the possible locations, and we throw an error.

To execute, use the call-operator `&` to execute the path stored in `$correctPath`. You can include any parameters after this as if you were invoking the binary by literal name instead of as a variable. The sample above uses one of your argument strings from the question as an example.

Comment: Thank you much, I just needed to put a ' in this line & $correctPath /configure -updatetype='bios,firmware,driver,application,utility,others'

Comment: Whoops, thanks for catching that! I've fixed it in the code above.

Comment: Appreciate the help, now I just need to get this deployed using our RMM